# Plot a cell array Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a cell array with arrays inside, how can I plot this?

```
data = {[1,2], [5,6], [9,15]}
```

I want to plot the arrays like points.

```
P(x,y) = P(1,2)
P(x,y) = P(5,6)
```

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
mat = reshape(cell2mat(data),2,size(data,2));
scatter(mat(1,:),mat(2,:));
```

Comment: I love you with all my heart.